Accessing nested plist?
To access nested plists I define
(defun plist-gett (nested &rest keys)
  (while keys
    (setq nested (plist-get nested (car keys)))
    (setq keys (cdr keys)) )
  nested )

to write things like
(setq foo-bar-end (plist-get tree :foo :bar :end))

and wonder if there is something already available. I could not find anything in the documentation index and neither in the jsonrpc.el which is the source of the nested plists.

I would write it somewhat differently, but that’s fine. These kinds of things are simple enough that you can write your own.
